# Where to ask questions about Apache and WAMP

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As above. Just to avoid confusions, and prevent pro trolling... I wonder if there is dedicated place to  ask questions about Apache and WAMP

Comment: What sort of question exactly? Apache and WAMP questions could be appropriate on quite a few sites, depending on exactly what they are asking.

Comment: its like domain related. Access control / access trouble when using computer name access the localhost instead of localhost itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are facing some issues with creating/managing the server; you can ask the questions on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

If you want help with configurations and settings of Apache/MySQL/PHP etc; I'd suggest [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

From [your comment](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237189/where-to-ask-questions-about-apache-and-wamp#comment777528_237189), I'd suggest you to as it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

> #### NOTE
>
> Do read the respective site's tour/help/faq page to get a general idea
>   of what type of questions are welcomed there.